# Binding to List element when element number changes

Tags: wpf, list, binding

```
        private List<Report> _reports = new List<Report>();
        public Report CurrentReport
        {
            get { return _reports[_componentIterator]; }
            set { _reports[_componentIterator] = value; }
        }
```

I have a _reports field and it's a list of Report objects.

I use a CurrentReport property to access current Report object based on _componentIterator.

How do I bind to some of Report properties so that changing _componentIterator won't break my binding?

If I bind like this, every _componentIterator change breaks binding.

```
           Binding designatorTextBlockBinding = new Binding(nameof(CurrentReport.Designator));
            designatorTextBlockBinding.Source = CurrentReport;
            _artifactControl.DesignatorTextBlock.SetBinding(Controls.TextBlock.TextProperty, designatorTextBlockBinding);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare the Binding like shown below, and make sure the `CurrentReport` property fires a change notification.

```
var designatorTextBlockBinding = new Binding
{
    Path = new PropertyPath("CurrentReport.Designator"),
    Source = this
};
```

or

```
var designatorTextBlockBinding = new Binding
{
    Path = new PropertyPath(
        nameof(CurrentReport) + "." + nameof(CurrentReport.Designator)),
    Source = this
};
```

or

```
var designatorTextBlockBinding = new Binding(
    nameof(CurrentReport) + "." + nameof(CurrentReport.Designator))
{
    Source = this
};
```

Comment: Omg thank you, it works. What's the difference between "CurrentReport.Designator" and nameof(CurrentReport.Designator)? First works and the other one doesn't.

Comment: `nameof(CurrentReport.Designator)` returns the name of that property, i.e. `"Designator"`. You could of course also write `nameof(CurrentReport) + "." + nameof(Report.Designator)`.

Comment: Great, I get it. Thanks.